# error with conjure-up access denied for Cuba

Tags: openstack, conjure-up

I was trying to install Openstack with conjure-up on ubuntu 16.04. It turns out that conjure-up at some point consumes the domain sentry.io, which is inaccessible from Cuba. Access from Cuba to that domain is blocked by the US government. It will be possible to modify some script in conjure-up so that you do not consume or consult something in that domain sentry.io or I will have to use VPN? Finally the installation process fail.

Answer (score 0):

Conjure-up uses sentry as a crash report. This encounter with error and want to submit the crash report to the senty.io but, it isn't possible because of accessing sentry is blocked by your governments. This isn't your actual problem, to find out the actual error message open the log file (~/.cache/conjure-up/conjure-up.log). The first error message before sentry errors is your actual error message.